# Combine same value from column 1 and add totals from column 2

Tags: excel, group-by, excel-formula, reporting

I have sku numbers in column 1 and qty in column 2.  I need a formula to be able to look at all the product numbers in column 1 and add up the qty in column 2 so the same sku and qty is all on one row.

Example:

```
SKURCD  QTY
100095  1
100095  1
100121  1
12172   1
15440   1
16637   1
21674   1
24567   1
2789    1
3514    1
36816   1
36819   1
42734   1
42734   1
```

Needs to look like:

```
SKURCD  QTY
100095  2
100121  1
12172   1
15440   1
16637   1
21674   1
24567   1
2789    1
3514    1
36816   1
36819   1
42734   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use pivottables for something like this.

You can use =sumif() but only on a static list. Else you'll have to keep updating your list of  SKUs

Comment: Hello, can you please explain or provide a formula for me to copy/paste?  I'm very novice.  The sku list and qty will change every time.

Comment: Got it, youtubed pivottable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that using pivot table could be the best way to do so. You can do it by selecting all the data and click the menu of Data-->PivotTable and PivotChart Report.